# If cameraX's videoCapture and ImageAnlaysis are used together, the preview becomes strange. What should I do? & How can I draw on a video frame?

Tags: video-capture, android-camerax, ondraw, google-mlkit

1. When cameraX's videoCapture and ImageAnlaysis are used together, the preview is rotated 90 degrees, and the recorded video in the gallery is longer than the actual length. why is this happening?

```kotlin
private fun bindUseCase() {
        if (cameraProvider == null) {
            return
        }

        if (analysisUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider!!.unbind(analysisUseCase)
        }

        if (imageProcessor != null) {
            imageProcessor!!.stop()
        }

        if (!PreferenceUtils.isCameraLiveViewportEnabled(this.context)) {
            return
        }

        if (previewUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider!!.unbind(previewUseCase)
        }

        val previewBuilder = Preview.Builder()
        previewUseCase = previewBuilder.build()
        previewUseCase!!.setSurfaceProvider(previewView!!.surfaceProvider)

        val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
            .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
            .build()

        videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

        imageProcessor =
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Using Face Detector Processor")
                val faceDetectorOptions = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
                    .enableTracking()
                    .build()

                FaceDetectorProcessor(this.context, faceDetectorOptions)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG,"imageProcessor",e)
                return
            }

        val builder = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        analysisUseCase = builder.build()

        needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = true

        analysisUseCase?.setAnalyzer(
            // imageProcessor.processImageProxy will use another thread to run the detection underneath,
            // thus we can just runs the analyzer itself on main thread.
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.context),
            ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy: ImageProxy ->
                if (needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo) {
                    val isImageFlipped = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                    val rotationDegrees = imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
                    if (rotationDegrees == 0 || rotationDegrees == 180) {
                        graphicOverlay!!.setImageSourceInfo(imageProxy.width, imageProxy.height, isImageFlipped)
                    } else {
                        graphicOverlay!!.setImageSourceInfo(imageProxy.height, imageProxy.width, isImageFlipped)
                    }
                    needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = false
                }
                try {
                    imageProcessor!!.processImageProxy(imageProxy, graphicOverlay)


                } catch (e: MlKitException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to process image. Error: " + e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        )
        Log.d(TAG,"$cameraProvider, $cameraSelector, $analysisUseCase, $imageProcessor,$previewUseCase")
        cameraProvider!!.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector!!,analysisUseCase,videoCapture,previewUseCase)
    }
```

If you subtract "analysisUseCase" from the code above, the preview and recording time come out normally.

2.
I want to draw the result of face recognition on a video frame. Currently, it is drawn only on the preview, but I want the result to be recorded together. What should I do?

Comment: Which version of CameraX are you using? I suggest you trying out the latest 1.3.0-beta01 version. Also, if you could try out the LifecycleCameraController API, it might fix your problem. Drawing into video however is a hard problem. We are working on a feature for that but there is no ETA. Here is a working-in-process prototype if you are interested: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2650821